# Excel VBA Runtime Error 9 but not when stepping through the code

Tags: vba, excel

What would the reason be for a VBA user form with an EventHandler class to throw a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

BUT

If I F8 and step into the UserForm code I can step right through the entire code without it crashing

Just for simplicity here is my event handler class LabelEventHandler

```
Private WithEvents Innerlabel As MSForms.Label

Private InnerRow As Integer
Private InnerSheet As Worksheet

Public Property Set Label(ByVal InLabel As MSForms.Label)
    Set Innerlabel = InLabel
End Property

Public Property Let Row(ByVal InRow As Integer)
    InnerRow = InRow
End Property

Public Property Set Sheet(ByVal InSheet As Worksheet)
    Set InnerSheet = InSheet
End Property

Private Sub InnerLabel_Click()
    Dim Frame As MSForms.Frame
    Dim ChildLabel As MSForms.Label
    Set Frame = Innerlabel.Parent
    For Each ChildLabel In Frame.Controls
        Select Case ChildLabel.Name
            Case "FullName"
                InnerSheet.Cells(InnerRow, 4).Value = ChildLabel.Caption
            Case "Email"
                InnerSheet.Cells(InnerRow, 5).Value = ChildLabel.Caption
            Case "Phone"
                InnerSheet.Cells(InnerRow, 6).Value = ChildLabel.Caption
        End Select
    Next
 End Sub
```

and here is the UserForm code

```
Private Sheet As Worksheet

Private LabelClickArray() As New LabelEventHandler

Public Sub AddUser(FullName As String, Email As String, Phone As String)
    Dim FullNameLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim EmailLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim PhoneLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim UserFrame As Frame
    Dim Top
    Top = FindBottomUserRow()
    Set UserFrame = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")

    With UserFrame
        .Top = Top
        .Left = 5
        .Width = 660
        .Height = 20
        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Weight = 400
        .Caption = ""
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
    End With

    Set FullNameLabel = UserFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    Set EmailLabel = UserFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    Set PhoneLabel = UserFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

    With FullNameLabel
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = 200
        .Height = 15
        .Name = "FullName"
        .Caption = FullName
    End With
    With EmailLabel
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 205
        .Width = 300
        .Height = 15
        .Name = "Email"
        .Caption = Email
    End With
    With PhoneLabel
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 510
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 15
        .Name = "Phone"
        .Caption = Phone
    End With

    ReDim Preserve LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) + 3)

    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 2).Label = FullNameLabel
    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 1).Label = EmailLabel
    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray)).Label = PhoneLabel

    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 2).Sheet = Sheet
    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 1).Sheet = Sheet
    Set LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray)).Sheet = Sheet

    LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 2).Row = ActiveCell.Row
    LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) - 1).Row = ActiveCell.Row
    LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray)).Row = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub


Function FindBottomUserRow()
    Dim Frame As Control
    Dim Top
    Top = 30
    For Each Frame In Me.Controls
        If (TypeName(Frame) = "Frame" And Frame.Top > Top) Then Top = Frame.Top
    Next
    If (Top > 30) Then Top = Top + 20
    FindBottomUserRow = Top
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    Me.AddUser "Ryan", "ryan@r.com", "2625"
    Me.AddUser "Jeff", "j@k.com", "123-4567"
End Sub
```

The error [image: From Running the user form by clicking Run or F5]

Comment: What line is generating the error?

Comment: @Comintern if i knew that i would not have to post here.

If i hit F5 or click the run button while the user form is active in the script editor it just yells at me about the runtime error 9 doesn't give me line numbers or anything

Comment: Well, that seems to narrow it down to `InnerLabel_Click` then. The only subscript accesses in that procedure are the calls to `.Cells`. I'd throw a `Debug.Print InnerRow` in there right above the `Select Case ChildLabel.Name` line and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: try adding a couple `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now)` lines in your code to see if slowing down some parts helps remove the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens at the `ReDim Preserve` command, because you never initialized the array. You cannot execute a `UBound`-function to a non-initialized array (if you try, you get the Runtime error 9). If you cannot be sure at runtime if your array in already initialized, change your code to:

```
If IsArrayAllocated(LabelClickArray) Then
    ReDim Preserve LabelClickArray(UBound(LabelClickArray) + 3)
Else
    ReDim LabelClickArray(3)
End If
```

The function `IsArrayAllocated` looks like this:

```
Function IsArrayAllocated(arr As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(arr) _
                   And Not IsError(LBound(arr, 1)) _
                   And LBound(arr, 1) <= UBound(arr, 1)

End Function
```

(Code copied from  [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx))

Comment: Funny I was just coming on here to answer my own question when i realized the same thing last night in the middle of some refactoring. But yep spot on answer. I do like the IsArrayAllocated function i might use that instead of my approach.